# In Excel VBA, why removing duplicate entries in a range removes the cell background color?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, cells

My Worksheet has Grey Color for all cells. I'm selecting a range in a column and removing the duplicates.  It removes the duplicates as intended but it also makes the duplicate cell's color to its default white. I tried multiple examples but looks like they were done with default white color and likely this issue would have never occurred. I can programatically set the color back to its original but I don't want to do so before knowing why it is happening this way. Following is my Code

```
LastRow = GetLastRow(SheetName, ConsolidatedColumn) 'ConsolidatedColumn is "P"
WS.Range(ConsolidatedColumn & "1:" & ConsolidatedColumn & LastRow) _
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```

Can someone explain why this happening?.

Comment: .RemoceDuplicates removes everything in the cell, also the formating. it is like a .clear command. If you don't want that, you can write a macro which only deletes the value

Comment: You are deleting the rows and shifting rows below them up not clearing the content.

Comment: @Jeeped: see my answer about the _not-deleting-but-just-shifiting-rows_ behavior of `RemoveDuplicates`.

Comment: @user3598756 - If you have data in A1:E9 and delete B5:C9 with the option to shift rows up you would get the same type of behavior as the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) using only column B:C. The deleted rows are being filled with unformatted blank cells from below.

Comment: @Jeeped: I must have not been clear. My side note (and consequent tests) was about the issue that the _original_ range is not _affected_ (in this case not _shortened_) by the `RemoveDuplicate()` method, so that you can still use it with its original reference. While the _delete&shift rowsup_ way affects it. No way I was saying `RemoveDuplicate()` doesn't clear duplicated cells, and that's why I put in the `.Copy` & `PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
With Worksheets(SheetName).Range(ConsolidatedColumn & "1:" & ConsolidatedColumn & LastRow)
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
    .Resize(1, 1).Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
```

other than that I throw in some (possibly) useful side notes about the functionality of `RemoveDuplicates()` method

it seems it doesn't *delete&shift* rows but just *shift* them
at least this is what I came up to via the following tests

**test1:**

```
With Worksheets(SheetName).Range(ConsolidatedColumn & "1:" & ConsolidatedColumn & LastRow)
    MsgBox .Address
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
    MsgBox .Address
    .Resize(1, 1).Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
```

where you get the same range addresses from the two `MsgBox` statements

and the last two statements extend the formatting to the whole *original* range

**test2:**

```
With Worksheets(SheetName).Range(ConsolidatedColumn & "1:" & ConsolidatedColumn & LastRow)
    MsgBox .Address
    .Rows(2).Delete
    MsgBox .Address
    .Resize(1, 1).Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
```

where you get a different range addresses from the two `MsgBox` statements, the second being one row shorter then the first

and, as a consequence, the last two statements don't extend the formatting to the whole *original* range

Comment: that was awesome. What an explanation!. I have used the following finally,  `With WS.Range(ConsolidatedColumn & "2:" & ConsolidatedColumn & LastRow)`  `.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes`  `.Resize(1).Copy`  ` .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`  `Application.CutCopyMode = False`  `End With`  `WS.Cells(1.1).Select 'To unselect the range of duplicates`

Comment: Glad it helped. If you found my answer useful you may want to up-vote it. Cheers